# how do I use an equals method to check fields in different objects to see if they are equals?

Tags: c#, equals, gethashcode

How do i use an objects equals() and the gethashcode() method to check the an objects field value to see if it is true?

for example order numbers

I have several different objects that I am initiating and I need to run an equals() method to check them to see if they are equals.

Comment: How about you show us your code

Answer (score 0):

Override both `Equals()` and `GetHasCode()` with your own implementation and then you don't have to rely on the default implementation in `Object` type and you'll have full control over what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If the objects that you are referring to are your own custom classes, then you will need to override the [Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [GetHashcode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods.

Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person p1 = new Person { FirstName = "Manny", Birthday = new DateTime(1970, 1, 4) };
        Person p2 = new Person { FirstName = "Moe", Birthday = new DateTime(1970, 1, 4) };
        Person p3 = new Person { FirstName = "Manny", Birthday = new DateTime(1970, 1, 4) };

        Console.WriteLine("p1 = p2? {0}", p1.Equals(p2));
        Console.WriteLine("p2 = p3? {0}", p2.Equals(p3));
        Console.WriteLine("p1 = p3? {0}", p1.Equals(p3));

        Console.WriteLine("p1 Hash = {0}", p1.GetHashCode());
        Console.WriteLine("p2 Hash = {0}", p2.GetHashCode());
        Console.WriteLine("p3 Hash = {0}", p3.GetHashCode());    
    }
}

class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    // You define what an equaled object is. 
    // In this example, we will say a Person is equal if they have the same
    // FirstName and Birthday
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        bool equals = false;
        if (obj is Person)
        {
            Person p = (Person)obj;
            if (p.FirstName == this.FirstName && p.Birthday == this.Birthday)
                equals = true;
        }
        return equals;
    }

    // You define what the hashcode of the object is. 
    // In this example, we will define the hashcode as the 
    // concatenation of the FirstName and Birthday
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}", this.FirstName, this.Birthday).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

The output of the program will be...

```
p1 = p2? False
p2 = p3? False
p1 = p3? True
p1 Hash = 1727998619
p2 Hash = 1625318294
p3 Hash = 1727998619
```